# Predicting the solubility of sulfate salts

Tags: thermodynamics, solubility

I came across a problem that asks to predict the solubility of alkaline earth metal sulfates: Magnesium, calcium, strontium and barium sulfates. I know that the spontaneity of dissolving can be roughly understood, in terms of lattice energy and the hydration enthalpies of the resulting cation and the anion. In this case, the anions are the same, so the enthalpy of hydration of an anion is the same for every salt. As for the lattice energy and the enthalpy of cation hydration, these two get smaller as the cation gets bigger. They have an opposing effects on solubility. so, how is it possible to predict the relative solubility at all in this case?

Comment: The question is not identical but there is an answer suitable for both questions.

Comment: From that question, I found this website "http://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group2/problems.html", the explanation to me is more convincing than the ones in the question itself. I found the answer.